# Asp.net textbox setting bordercolor from code behind then removing it

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I am changing textbox bordercolor from code behind.

tname.BorderColor = Color.Red

Later on I want to remove the border and show the textbox in the same form it was before.I tried setting border colour to grey and changing border style but it doesnt look like the original textbox without styling.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `Color.Empty` to set back to default.